# Apache Avro - Read binary stream

Tags: python, apache-kafka, binary, avro

I'm trying to build a Kafka consumer who ingests Avro stream messages.
This is the resource that I follow to read Avro message file and works: (https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html)

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = DataFileReader(open("weather.avro", "rb"), DatumReader(avro.schema.parse(open("mySchema.avsc").read())))
for user in reader:
    print (user)
reader.close()
```

But, my question is, How to read Avro stream instead of a file?

I tried something like this but returns me wrong values.

```
def avro_decoder(msg_value):
    schema = avro.schema.parse(open("mySchema.avsc").read())
    reader = DatumReader(schema)
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    message_bytes.seek(5)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict
```

This is the schema

```
schema = {
              "type": "record",
              "name": "Weather",
              "namespace": "test",
              "doc": "A weather reading.",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "station",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "name": "time",
                  "type": "long"
                },
                {
                  "name": "temp",
                  "type": "int"
                }
              ]
            }
```

And this is the avro message:

```
Objavro.codecnullavro.schemaú{"type": "record", "doc": "A weather reading.", "name": "test.Weather", "fields": [{"name": "station", "type": "string"}, {"name": "time", "type": "long"}, {"name": "temp", "type": "int"}]} ñKœV^¤‹ÿŸÕ>Z:v&011990-99999˜ÒïÖ
 ñKœV^¤‹ÿŸÕ>Z:v
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: `confluent_kafka` works with Confluent Schema Registry. Ideally you shouldn't be passing the entire schema within each message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just I figured out what it was the problem.
So the problem was that I was sending wrong message! I sent the message as it is inside of the .avro file, but in reality, the correct had to be like this one: 123111